# Looping through string values from a windows command line bat file

Tags: windows, for-loop, command-line

I am trying to create a batch script for my Windows machine that loops through a list of (string/decimal) values and uses each value as a parameter inside the loop.

Below is an example of a simple for loop I would like to use to display all the different version files (from my list)

```
FOR ? in ('1.1','1.2','2.4','3.9') do echo V[value_from_for_loop].txt
```

I am having trouble in how to loop through each item and use a variable in my echo statement.

Comment: Is that syntax pseudo-code or is it from another language?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
for %x in (1.1 1.2 2.4 3.9) do echo V%x.txt
```

For use in a batch file you'll have to double the `%`:

```
for %%x in (1.1 1.2 2.4 3.9) do echo V%%x.txt
```

Comment: What if the strings happen to include `?` or `*`? Is there a way to prevent the command-interpreter from interpreting them as filenames?

Comment: I'm using Git for Windows "bash" shell (MINGW32) and I get 

`bash": syntax error near unexpected token `('`.

Comment: @DaveHeq: Don't use bash and try to execute cmd commands, then.

Answer (score 54):

@Јοеу's answer works great,

here is how I've used it, to 'walk' a pre-set list of files in a specific order.

```
@echo off
for %%x in (
        a.js
        storage.js
        logic.js
        main.js
        z.js
       ) do (
         echo your file name is %%x
         echo "%%x" is a cool name
         echo.
         echo =-=-=-=-=-=
         echo.
       )
```

the reason it looks like a vertical list is so it will be easier to add or remove more items. (and 'echo' with 'dot' is for one empty line).

the output will look like this:

```
C:\example>yourBatchName.cmd
your file name is a.js
"a.js" is a cool name

=-=-=-=-=-=

your file name is storage.js
"storage.js" is a cool name

=-=-=-=-=-=

your file name is logic.js
"logic.js" is a cool name

=-=-=-=-=-=

your file name is main.js
"main.js" is a cool name

=-=-=-=-=-=

your file name is z.js
"z.js" is a cool name

=-=-=-=-=-=
```

** p.s. for file name listing one should prefer using something like this:

`for %%e in (*.dll) do (....`

Answer (score 15):

Assume you have a very long list of values which will be very uncomfortable to type on the commandline. Also, there is a length limit for the DOS command line.

In this case the values may be stored in an arbitrarily long file, one per line. Call it `my-values.list`, with a content similar to:

```
1.1
1.2
2.4
3.9
3.9.1
3.9.2
3.91
3.91.1
...
```

Now you could read the variables from this text file, line by line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in (c:\path\to\my-values.list) do echo.  Version%~nxa.txt
```

Comment: @David Liddle: Of course it has -- you just don't understand (yet) how  :-) -- Assume a very long text file `values.list`, where you have all the values listed, 1 per line. Would be very un-handy to type all these on the commandline again (which itself has length limits). I had to do exactly that thing with ~2.500 values a couple of weeks ago. And the list I had created thru another batch. I just didn't need to simply+boringly `do echo ...` but more interesting stuff instead... ;-)

Comment: What is the function of ~nx in %~nxa?

Comment: @matty: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679781/359307

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, I believe:

```
for %x in (1.1 1.2 2.4 3.9) do (
    echo V%x.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me comment, but I wanted to add my 2 cents worth here.
The ' do ' has to be on the same line as the right parenthesis of the 'for' command. In other words, this will work:

```
for %x in (1.1 1.2 2.4 3.9) do echo V%x.txt
```

...but this will not:

```
for %x in (1.1 1.2 2.4 3.9)
    do echo V%x.txt
```

Comment: You can put a  ( before the echo and put a 0 after the txt which will allow you to put echo on it's own line.
`for %x in (1.1 1.2 2.4 3.9)  do (
    echo V%x.txt
)`