# Move folders to parent level (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, move, subdirectory

My file tree looks like this:

1. Parent folder

   - Subfolder

     - Subsubfolder
   - Subfolder

     - Subsubfolder
   - Subfolder

     - Subsubfolder

I'd like to move all `subsubfolders` to the parent folder without changing the structure of the `subsubfolders`. How do I do this?

Comment: `For /d %A in ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\David\Documents\Assorted\*") do move "%A" "%A\..\..\%~nxA"` See `for /?` and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch

Answer (score -1):

Create a move.bat in the parent folder and run this:

```
FOR /R "." %%F IN (.) DO (
move "%%F" ".")
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276986/4934937