# Having problems with make file within git

Tags: makefile, arduino-uno

I am a complete newbie when using git.

I am trying to compile/make this compile this git repository but without much success.

https://github.com/cithraidt/lwcloneu2

Every time I try to create the file using make I get the following errors

```
for i in arduino_mega2560 arduino_leonardo arduino_uno breakout_32u2 arduino_promicro; do make --directory=$i clean; make --directory=$i all; done
i was unexpected at this time.
makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 255
```

Once again I am a complete newbie at this and would gratefully accept any advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  More urgently, you need to read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Please don't rely only on an external site to give us information.  The question should be self-contained, though you might reference an external site to let us know where more complete information can be obtained.  It's hard to guess what's wrong without the lines in the makefile that trigger the complaint.  It may be that you didn't indent the line with the `for` loop with a tab, or it may be something else altogether.  That's why we need an MCVE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through string values from a windows command line bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439954/looping-through-string-values-from-a-windows-command-line-bat-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us the critical information, that you're trying to do this on Windows.  I can tell that you are, because the error message *i was unexpected at this time.* is a message printed by the Windows terminal command line.

That makefile is written for a POSIX system such as GNU/Linux.  You won't be able to use it on Windows, without a lot of modification.

According to the README file there are Visual Studio project files available in the Git repository; I expect you'll need to use those to rebuild this code on Windows.

Comment: Thank you MadScientist. Sorry I should of put windows when making the post.

I will try and create the file on linux.